# Obtener el tipo de cambio Paypal

Tags: paypal

He visto que Paypal te permite cobrar en unas 22 tipos de monedas, pero no lo hace en la moneda de Perú (Nuevos Soles), y resulta que lo que intento cobrar es un recibo cuyo monto ya esta en PEN. Asi que lo que se me ocurre es convertirlo a dolares (USA), y luego Paypal, internamente, de acuerdo a las tarjetas de los clientes los vuelva a convertir y cobrar en soles. Pero para que esto sea exacto necesito el tipo de cambio que utiliza Paypal en su conversion (para yo poder hacerlo de soles a dolares antes de enviarselo a Paypal).

Alguien sabe si Paypal da este tipo de servicio? quizas en su REST API? o quizas me recomiendan otro tipo de estrategia?

Comment: Si lo tiene https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/

Comment: Gracias por responder jasilva.
Estaba viendo el link que dejaste, y en su detalle indica que las monedas disponibles para la conversion son esas 22 de las que hable, en donde no figura el sol peruano? Tambien funciona para soles peruanos? ya que no esta en esa lista?

Comment: Si no lo soporta lamentablemente no lo podras usar, tocaria hacer algo a mano y quiza mandar el paso en USD, ya convertido

Comment: a mano, eso es lo que estoy haciendo en realidad, pero al no tener el mismo tipo de cambio que utiliza paypal nada me garantiza que cuando paypal le cobre al cliente (nuevamente en soles) sea otro importe, justamente por diferencia en el tipo de cambio.

Comment: Si, lamentablemente hasta que no incluyan soles en su api, no habra forma exacta del cobro, solo aproximada